# Sprite being rendered incorrectly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css-sprites

I have a page with a button with a background image (sprite).  When I do not put my sprite in a table, I get repeated images scattered diagonally across the web browser, and no gallery.  In HTML source view, everything looks fine, but if I go to the Inspector, it looks different, repeating buttons that I created diagonally from right to left going down.

**Update:**

I just realized that another way to get this working was to change:

```
<a href="../Gallery/Create" class="l_new" />
```

to

```
<a href="../Gallery/Create" class="l_new" ></a>
```

This is no hardship.  The only thing I can think of is this must be some bug in my version of @renderbody used with _layout.chtml (I'm using the one generated by visual studio).

Looks like this is going to continue being a mystery but I'll keep my question posted, just in case.

The l_new style contains sprite info:

```
.l_new
{
width: 170px;
height: 36px;
background-position: -43px -155px;
background-image: url('img/sprites.png?v=6');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
display:block;
}
```

I could not find anything unusual about the HTML, except the fact that it is in a section tag which I've never used before, and I do not see any javascripts running.

If I enclose the sprite in a table, everything is normal.

Here is what it looks like with Chrome's inspector.  It does the same thing in IE9.  I have not posted the HTML source, but believe me it's totally normal, and does not reflect the output below.

[image]

And here is an example of the index.chtml file which results in the issue:

```
@model List<AutoShow_MVC.Models.GalleryModel>
@using AutoShow_MVC.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Photo Gallery</h2>

<a href="../Gallery/Create" class="l_new" />
```

Comment: Can you show us some code or real time problem/screen shot. that will be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: Just added the screenshot and the index.chtml file.  Thanks.

Comment: I just deleted most the content of the index.chtml file and the problem still happens even with the basic index.chtml listed above.

Comment: The only reason I could think about... is that you have some CSS defined for tables... and that could be the reason of it working fine. You could use Firebug in Firefox to see what CSS classes are used selecting a button...

Comment: @Dave can you upload your files some and show us the demo so we can identify the problem in real time. we are getting your problem but it is better to understand, so please show real time/working pages.

Comment: Please see my update.  Seems like a bug in RenderBody to me.  Sorry I can't provide my entire source, and as we have no idea what's causing this, it seems easiest just to use my workaround mentioned above.